# ajax works, but it doesn't insert into my sql query (js/php)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I don't understand if ajax work this way, but data doesn't add into my mysql database. I checked network tab in my chrome browser and found data has been forwarded.
I had tried like this way

script.js:

```
$(".btn_ranking").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
    var time = localStorage.getItem('timer_end');

    $.ajax({
        url: "php/file.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { "name": name, "time": time }
    })
});
```

file.php:

```
<?php

require_once "connect.php";

$polaczenie = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$time = $_POST['time'];

if ($polaczenie->connect_errno != 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $polaczenie->connect_errno;
} else {

    if ($rezultat = @$polaczenie->query("INSERT INTO ranking (id, name, time) VALUES (NULL, $name, $time)")) {
        echo "ok";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: might the $name sould be closed into quotes right? is a string?

Comment: Take of the `@`s and what do you get? If you are having issues with errors displaying on your site turn off the error displaying, don't just suppress the errors. You should still log them so you know what happens..

Comment: You are open to SQL injections and `$name,` would need to be quoted. Both issues would be solved with a parameterized query.

Comment: skorzystaj z PDO

Comment: change your ajax like `data: { name: name, time: time }`

Comment: Remove the `@` sign - perhaps an error is hiding there but you are silencing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,you had better use **PrepareStatement** to pass parameter instead of writing them directly into your sql.

For your current code,try change to below code

```
if ($rezultat = @$polaczenie->query("INSERT INTO ranking (id, name, time) VALUES (NULL, '".$name."', '".$time."')")) {
    echo "ok";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try like as below

```
$(".btn_ranking").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
    var time = localStorage.getItem('timer_end');

    $.ajax({
        url: "php/file.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { name: name, time: time } //Remove double quote
    })
});
```